# "Habitat selection in/of birds", "concept in/of statistics", "theme in/of evolution"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, collocation, in-of

It seems to me that *in* and *of* work equally well in sentences such as these:

> - - Habitat selection **in** birds is frequently studied.
>   - Habitat selection **of** birds is frequently studied.
> - - Variation is a key concept **in** statistics.
>   - Variation is a key concept **of** statistics.
> - - The function of behaviour is an important theme **in** evolution.
>   - The function of behaviour is an important theme **of** evolution.

Should either *in* or *of* be favoured in the above sentences?

Comment: I would prefer "in" in all three cases; "of" seems less apt. You could improve it some by making the object more explicit: "*of* evolutionary theory", for example.

Comment: This is easy to understand if the concept is clear, else very hard to explain the difference. Are you prepared for a long answer with patience? :)

Comment: Further complicating things, the instances as a class are not all the same, that is, the distinction brought about by the preposition change is for a different purpose.

Comment: @DanBron Every one of the six is grammatically correct and makes eminent sense. They mean different things, though.

Answer (score 2):

`of` in the first case and `in` in the second two.

The first case is referring to studying an action performed by a being. It's the action *of* birds being studied. I think with *of*, the sentence is equivalent to "Birds' habitat selection is frequently studied" as intended.

The second two are stating that some topic exists *in* some field.

Having said that I do not know a general rule to cite that will work for all such sentences =(.

Comment: "Having said that I do not know a general rule" so what's said is an educated opinion, not an answer, right?

Answer (score 0):

**in** in the first case, but either **in** or **or** in the second and third.

"habitat selection *of* birds" can be misparsed as referring to *how the habitat selects the birds*.

"habitat selection *in* birds" avoids this ambiguity.  The birds are the actors *in* the selection, not the objects *of* selection!

With the other two, neither preposition introduces any such ambiguity.